# AES Decryption - original characters replaced by weird characters

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt a json string using the below code:

```
public static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public static Cipher getDefaultCipherInstance(int mode)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException {
        byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode("encryptionKey".getBytes(CHARSET));

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("RandomVector".getBytes(CHARSET));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(mode, skeySpec, iv);

        return cipher;
    }

public static String encryptText(String plainText) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = getDefaultCipherInstance(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes(CHARSET));
            return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipherText));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Problem encryptingText",ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

public static String decryptText(String cipherText) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = getDefaultCipherInstance(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
            return new String(decrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.debug("Problem during decrypt text: " + cipherText, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It works fine most of the times but sometimes I see weird characters in the decrypted string like "\u001A=`�["Q�\u001D)��ۉ�d":\ , this is corrupting the json and we are not able to deserialize json to object.

Any idea what could be the problem here?

**Update::**

I added the following code to test encryption/decryption in a concurrent(multi-threaded) environment:

```
public class EncryptionTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);

        String text = "Hi there Ithanks for cimngng";

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Iteration: " + i);
            executorService.submit(new EncryptionRunnable(text));
        }

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }

    static class EncryptionRunnable implements Runnable {
        private String text;

        public EncryptionRunnable(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 10) {
                String encrypted = encryptText(text);
                String prefix = Thread.currentThread().getName() + "::" + i + ":: ";
                System.out.println(prefix + "encrypted:: " + encrypted);
                try {
                    System.out.println(prefix + "decrypted:: " + decryptText(encrypted));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(prefix + "decrypted:: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see that all of the outputs were correct but for one of the output, it produced strange characters like this:

pool-1-thread-5::0:: decrypted:: ȼ����S}�q��j� for cimngng

Even the encrypted string is same for every encryption. Can anybody help now? Note: I am using the same cipher instance for encryption and same for decryption.

Here is a snapshot of the output of the above code.

[image: Output]

Comment: Is it ensured that encryption and decryption use the same IV? While the IV for encryption and decryption must be identical, different encryptions must use different (random) IVs for security reasons (the code doesn't look like this). Apart from that, the code should work. However, in `decryptText()` the encoding should be specified when decoding (`new String(decrypted, CHARSET)`). Post test data: Sample key, IV, ciphertext, plaintext.

Comment: Yes IV and encryption key are same for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: As said, currently not reproducible. Does the issue occur reproducibly for the **same** data (same key, same IV, same plaintext)? If yes, post example data. If no, the posted code is more likely not the problem, are there specifics of the environment?

Comment: The examples where the decryption is adding weird characters, I won't be able to post the sample data because we don't have it as we store it in encrypted form. I just want to get an idea where it might go wrong, I have looked at a few blogs, it can be related to encoding but not sure. And yeah it is same key, same IV. And when I try to reproduce it locally using Unit Test, it is not reproducible.

Comment: Fix the encoding issues in your code (also in `encryptText()`: `new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipherText), CHARSET)`). The fact that the problem is not reproducible locally and is only intermittent suggests an environment-specific problem (something like multithreading etc.), so it's hard to tell from the information what the problem is.

Comment: OK thanks, will try that.

Comment: First check that the expected character encoding is the same before encryption and after decryption.  Then compare input and output byte by byte, rather than as characters. That should help you get an idea where the problem is.

Comment: @Topaco I updated my question. Please check once if you have any clue.